# how to filter categories dynamicaly using php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-ui

I have one website and i want to filter it contents  by TYPE,SIZE and all.Like ebay .I don't know how to do this am new to php  anybody have code for this?? Thanks in advance

Comment: What content? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post you're own try.

Answer (score 0):

Ever considered http://www.prestashop.com/en/ ?

This website will allow you to do most of what you want easily

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ajax for dynamicaly filtering content on your web page. Like
http://www.codemashups.com/dynamic-search-filtering-using-jquery-and-php/
or 
you can use 
http://www.listjs.com/

Comment: not this one...i want code like this http://demo.iprogrammerindia.in/jquery/filter/ss